# How to use the method GetCellValue of GuiGridView

Tags: sap-gui

I wanna know how to use this method I found from the documentation of SAP GUI. But how do I use it?

Documentation from [GuiGridView object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiGridView&product=sap_gui_for_windows):

> Public Function GetCellValue( _ 
> ByVal Row As Long, _ 
> ByVal Column As String _ 
> ) As String
>
> Returns the value of the cell as a string.

Could you provide me an example?

Comment: Please say explicitly what you want to do. This method returns a String, it's a read method, not a write method, so you can't assign a value (`=`).

Comment: I would like an example of it

Comment: Do you want an example of `GetCellValue`, or an example how to change the value in a cell? If it's second case, please edit your question (title and body).

Comment: I wanna an example of GetCellValue. I just edited the question! ^^

Comment: In VBA it would be something like that: `CellValue = gridview.GetCellValue(5,"COLUMNNAME")` to get the cell value from row 5, column "COLUMNNAME". And before that you could have `Set gridview = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")`. Now, I don't think it helps a lot because you find that anywhere in the Web...

Comment: It did help, Sandra. Thanks! I find it weird that the documentation doesn't give any example.

Comment: SAP GUI Scripting is provided with minimal documentation without any example.